# Campos de inputs muito grandes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Ao copiar e colar um código simples de um formulário de exemplo no site do bootstrap, ocorre o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque esses campos estão assim ? Sendo que segundo o exemplo deveriam ser bem menores.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
      <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença é que no exemplo o código está dentro de um [Container](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#containers) (classe container).

A classe `container` não aparece no exemplo porque, geralmente, ela é única por página. Mas, se você analisar o código fonte da página do exemplo, verá que ela está lá com os os seus respectivos valores.

Veja a imagem abaixo para entender melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para exemplificar o que é feito, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
      <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Repare que no início do seu código eu adicionei uma `div` com a classe `container`. Para exemplificar eu diminui o `width` dela para `400px`, mas o bootstrap faz isso por você.

Note que não é somente os `inputs` que seguem o tamanho, mas sim todos os elementos dentro do `container`.

Caso ache que o tamanho é maior ou menor do que o que deseja, você pode customizar da forma que achar melhor.